# Camel SMTP subscriber?

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail, apache-camel

Does Apache Camel have any components for pulling emails (and their attachments) down from an SMTP server, and onto a route?

We currently have a manual process where customers email us data, and then a human being cut's and pastes that data into a file, drops the file on an FTP server, and Java (Camel) software polls the FTP server and ingests the file onto a route.

I've been asked to take the human element out of the equation without disrupting what our customer's are used to.

So: customers still email us data to process, except, somehow, a Camel component reads the email directly.

**If no such component exists, what types/interfaces would need to be created or extended to make such a capability possible?**

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it has, check out [Camel Mail Component](http://camel.apache.org/mail.html) and in particular the "Samples" section, it has an example on how to poll a mailbox and forward emails to another route.